# How can I have a String variable have more than once instance?

Tags: java

```
public String foodstats (){
    String foodstats = "";
    for ( int i = 0; i < consumables.size(); i++){
         foodstats =  "Name: " + consumables.get(i).getName() + "\tNutrition: " + consumables.get(i).getNValue() + "\tStamina: " + consumables.get(i).getStamina() + "\n" ;
   }
    return foodstats;
}
```

So this returns: `Name: Water    Nutrition: 30    Stamina : 15`

I realize why its doing this, the second time the for loop runs through it replaces the first item's stats and returns only the replaced stats.

Is there a way around this? I need to return all the item's stats based on the array list size.

Comment: What is the desired output

Comment: It's a little hard to understand exactly what you're aiming for here, but it seems like you probably want to use `+=` instead of `=`.  (But my mind-reading skills are a little off today.)

Comment: Or you want to return a `List<String>` instead of a `String`.

Comment: Basically its replacing the first item stats with the second, the desired output would be: Stats of Soup item, then stats of water as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a `StringBuilder`, more efficient in that case than `+=` concatenation :

```
public String foodstats (){
    StringBuilder foodstats = new StringBuilder();
    for ( int i = 0; i < consumables.size(); i++){
         foodstats.append("Name: " + consumables.get(i).getName() + "\tNutrition: " + consumables.get(i).getNValue() + "\tStamina: " + consumables.get(i).getStamina() + "\n");
   }
    return foodstats.toString();
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Although I'm curious what does .append do?

Comment: A `StringBuffer` holds an array of chars and expand its size when necessary. Basically, you can consider it as an arraylist of chars. Thus, `append` just tries to write the characters of the input string in the underlying array. If there is not enough space, a bigger array is allocated, the previous array is copied in it and finally the chars of the input string are written at the end

Answer (score 1):

Make a `StringBuilder` and use `append(...)` in the loop. Once you are done, call `toString()` on the result, like this:

```
StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
for ( int i = 0; i < consumables.size(); i++){
     res.append("Name: " + consumables.get(i).getName() + "\tNutrition: " + consumables.get(i).getNValue() + "\tStamina: " + consumables.get(i).getStamina() + "\n");
}
return res.toString();
```

Note: you could use `foodstats += ...` syntax, too, but that would be inferior, because each iteration of the loop would create a throw-away temporary object.

Answer (score 1):

```
public String foodstats()
    {
        StringBuilder foodstats = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < consumables.size(); i++)
        {
            foodstats.append("Name: "); 
            foodstats.append(consumables.get(i).getName());
            foodstats.append("\tNutrition: ");
            foodstats.append(consumables.get(i).getNValue());
            foodstats.append("\tStamina: ");
            foodstats.append(consumables.get(i).getStamina());
            foodstats.append("\n");
        }
        return foodstats.toString();
    }
```